# Lost android phone

Tags: lost-phone, motorola-moto-e

i lost my phone
my phone model is MOTOROLA(MOTO-E)
when i lost it,that phone consists of 16 gb data

my question is how to find my phone or how to recover my data?

Comment: Check the Q&A tagged under [tag:lost-phone].

Comment: Or start with our [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info) for a summary. But @Firelord is correct: a little search would have revealed this question has been asked multiple times here already (which is why your question is being downvoted: "does not show any research effort"). Here's a search for [lost phone recover](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=lost+phone+recover+answers%3A1) on our site, which includes answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a backup stored somewhere (either online or your hard drive), you can't recover the data without finding your phone first.

Check out this post for finding the phone:
androidcentral.com/you-can-now-quickly-google-find-my-phone-find-lost-android-device